# Multi-touch on Robovm using Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I'm using libgdx 1.4.1 and robovm version 1.0.0-alpha-04.

I enabled Stage input by using : `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`and added two buttons to the screen that should be touched together.

When the first button is touched down the TouchDown Method return true but when trying to touch the second button (while keeping button one touched down) I get nothing.

How do I get it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue just enable multiple touch on your view.

```
viewController.getView().setMultipleTouchEnabled(true);
```